# Is it bad UX to reload a page during signup?

Tags: forms, web-app, signup-signon, refresh

During a sign up process for my web app, a full page reload is necessary after some processing that happens in AJAX (the user sees a loading animation for a few seconds, then the reload happens).

Does reloading the web page in the middle of the process create a bad user experience? If so, what can I do to mitigate it?

Comment: what are you changing with that ajax request? What is the porpuse of it?

Comment: @Tzach you've asked 10 questions on UX StackExchange without accepting a single answer.  Please go back and accept some answers as the community has volunteered time to help you out and you should at least acknowledge that,particularly if you want people to help you in the future here.  thanks.  See http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/50949/tzach

Comment: If you haven't collected their information already then yes, it would be bad. Otherwise its not great UX but acceptable to change page locations...

Answer (score 6):

It's best not to reload during a signup process, but sometimes it can't be avoided.  There are **many** signup processes for even very mature sites (e.g. gmail, ebay, etc) which involve page reloads.

---

#### What issues need to be addressed?

Page loads create cognitive disruption to users.  While you're filling in a form, the page becomes your universe so a reload suddenly causes the universe to disappear momentarily.  The disruption may trigger:

- **Disorientation** as the user loses bearings temporarily and needs to re-orient himself on the new page.
- **Regret or re-evaluation** as the user is momentarily distraction.  So for sensitive signup processes you the disruption may provide an excuse for abandonment.
- **Frustration** as the user may not have been expecting the page load and may feel frustrated that she has been moved forward involuntarily in the signup process.

---

#### What can be done?

Here are some practices which help mitigate the issues:

1. **Cue users that something is going to happen**.  A `Next` button, progress bar animation (which you're using) or a more descriptive `Next: edit your profile >` button helps users understand that they are about to move into a different step so the page load will be less unexpected.
2. **Help users regain orientation quickly** on the new page.
   Provide a clear entry point into the next page, for example a clear page title explaining what users should do, e.g. `Edit your profile`.

   - Provide consistency of style and layout (e.g. if you have a header and footer on the old page, make sure it also appears on the new page)
   - Provide additional orientation cues such as a wizard-style progress bar:
     [image]
3. **Provide positive reinforcement** to counteract regret/re-evaluation.  For example, the page header might start with `You're almost done...`.  There are many approaches here.  Adopting a conversational style with a user (if it's acceptable for your app) can help users feel more engaged with the process.
4. **Make sure the back button works!** This is quite important for addressing/avoiding user frustration.  A user may not have expected the page reload, or may need to go back and edit the previous form.  It's very frustrating for users to move forward in the process and not be able to go back...a typical reaction is just to abandon the process altogether.